# Eclipse Pydev: Undefined variable: print input

Tags: python, eclipse, parsing, pydev

So, I'm using eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a,20180405-1200) with Pydev Version 7.2.1.201904261721. I am learning python through a pdf, and on one restart, my code was spammed with "Undefined variable: print". However, when I interpret and run the code, everything is normal. Why does this happen? How do I fix this?
Here's my code (titled rock1.py in an individual project):

```py
'''
Created on Jan 29, 2019

@author: Aaron
'''
import random
choices= ["rock paper sissers "]
player=input("do you want to be rock paper or sissors  (or quit?)")
computer= random.choice("choices")
while player!=("quit"):
    print("you choose,"+player+",computers choose"+computer+".")
if player== computer:
    print("it's a tie")
else:
    print("computer wins")    
if player == ("rock"):
        if computer == ("sissors"):
            print("youwin")
elif player == ("sissors"):
        if computer==("paper" ):
            print("you win")
        elif player==("paper"):
            if computer== ("rock"):
                print("youwin")
            else:
                print("computer win")
        else:
                print ("i think there is a kind of error")
                print("i think there is a kind of error")
```

Errors(taken straight from eclipse problem tab):

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Undefined variable: input   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 7  PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 10 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 12 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 14 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 17 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 20 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 23 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 25 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 27 PyDev Problem
Undefined variable: print   rock1.py    /rock sissers paper line 28 PyDev Problem
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens when PyDev cannot communicate with the shell it spawns for getting builtin tokens (which is the case for `print` on Python 3).

Please take a look at http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowToFixCodeCompletion to see if it helps to solve your problem... You may also want to check if your interpreter is properly configured or if you have some error in your error log -- see: http://www.pydev.org/faq.html#HowdoIReportaBUG for details on getting the error log.

Comment: When I try to paste my error log, even when I try to omit unnecessary ones, I get over the character limit. Anyways, how do I check if I have some error?

Comment: I'm just gonna use the ones I see in the window instead of pasting it for the time being.